# Android Studio Column Selection

Tags: android-studio

Need Help,

How to disable column selection on android studio, I'm using linux.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is actually Alt + Shift + Insert!

Answer (score 8):

Double-press shift, start typing Column Selection and the switch for it should pop up in the search results.

Comment: No,  i mean when i highlight to some text, the cursor is not highlight complete.
Thank you